# installed TRAC and SVN on ubuntu server 12.04LTS - login not working, and no svn connection

Tags: svn

I am new to svn and trac. I successfully managed to set-up svn repo and even do my first commit :=) For project management I was advised to also install Trac.

I followed these instructions: http://www.subversionary.org/howto/setting-up-a-subversion-server-on-ubuntu-gutsy-gibbon-server

I had to chown svn repo folder to www-data otherwise I could not commit through http.

I did chown on trac folder too www-data.svn

So what is the problem?
why login does not work?

I have this:

```
<Location /trac/[[:alnum]]+/login">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
  Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /trac>
  SetHandler mod_python
  PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
  PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
  PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /var/www/trac
  PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac
</Location>
```

There is something I am missing, or not understanding on how Trac should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

changed this:

```
<Location /trac/[[:alnum]]+/login">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

to this:

```
<Location /trac/">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```